# resolve [authorization_request_not_found] when using oauth2-client as implicit grant-type

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

i'am getting OAuth2AuthorizationException:[authorization_request_not_found]

when trying to replace authorization-grant-type from authorization_code to implicit

```
 spring:
    security:
      oauth2:
        client:
          registration:
            mobile:
              provider: auth
              client-id: revo
              authorization-grant-type: implicit
              redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
              scope: read
```

the result of this redirect me to 
 /login/oauth2/code/mobile#access_token={++++}&token_type=bearer&state={++++}&expires_in={++++}

but it is Whitelabel Error Page
[image]
can i resolve this Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: Do you have a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: i'am using ServerHttpSecurity from spring webflux

Answer (score 2):

According to the source code, `authorization_request_not_found` could be caused by:

- registration does not exist (when auth server responds to a strange registration)
- state does not exist (auth server responds with a strange state)

The above should be kept in `ClientRegistrationRepository`. After checking the client and auth server configuration, the 3rd possibility is that server and client are using the same `{baseUrl}`, like both localhost or the same ip, even though they are at different ports. Then you can change one of them to use a local configured domain-name (e.g. /etc/host). This is because when both client and server are using the same domain-name, they erase session id the other one just set in cookie.